# Char cannot be dereferenced Issue with getNumericValue()

Tags: java, char

I'm trying to do a pyramid like:

```
a
bc
def
ghij 
klmno
```

but it gives me the error: `Char cannot be dereferenced`

I have a very easy code:

```
public class PiramideLetras {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        char cha = 'A';
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            for(int y=i;y>=0;y--){
                    System.out.print(cha);
                    int b = cha.getNumericValue();
                    }
            System.out.println("");}
    }
}
```

Why I get this error?

Comment: Try using `int b = Character.getNumericValue(cha);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Char.getNumericValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29) is a static method which takes the value as an argument. So you want:

```
int b = Char.getNumericValue(cha);
```

You can't use primitive types as the target of any kind of method call.